# Cannot connect to FTP via Filezilla on Lightsail

Tags: linux, debian, ftp, filezilla, proftpd

I created an instance of Debian on Amazon Lightsail. Everything works fine except FTP. I added port 21 to the firewall:
[image: port 21 added]

Next, I followed these instructions to the letter on how to install proftpd: https://www.tecmint.com/install-proftpd-in-ubuntu-and-debian/

As a last step, I added a password to the proftpd user and restarted the service. Then added an FTP connection in Filezilla with the following data: 
[image: filezilla data]

And I get the following error:

[image: incorrect data]

Does anyone use ftp with Lightsail?

Comment: Why FTP? Do yourself a favour an go with SFTP. If you notice, the log says *Login incorrect*, so I would start from there. Check the logs on the server. Please note that FTP needs data ports as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question:**

> Does anyone use ftp with Lightsail?

**Answer:**
Probably not.

**Explanation:**
FTP is a very old protocol that has some drawbacks (uses random ports, no encryption...). Lightsail was launched in 2016, when most companies had already switched from FTP to FTPS or SFTP. There still are use cases for FTP but I doubt many would use it to communicate with their servers hosted on a service such as Lightsail.

---

If the goal is to update WordPress plugins, I recommend using [wp-cli](https://wp-cli.org/) instead of going through the hassle of setting up a FTP server.

Comment: I use SFTP to transfer files by FileZilla. I have sites on WordPress, and I can update plugins via FTP or FTPS. I used FTP on OVH. I'll try to configure FTPS instead. Thanks.

Comment: @sirDexter Why not SFTP?

Comment: In WordPress I have only two connection types for updating plugins:
1. FTP
2. FTPS (SSL)

Comment: [wp-cli](https://wp-cli.org/) is how you (should) update WordPress plugins.

Comment: Thank you for the great alternative that I wasn't aware of.

Comment: @simlev there are still plenty of reasons to use FTP with Lightsail. Almost all of them involve integrating with legacy systems and organisations that haven't moved with the times. ;)

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for connecting lightsail to filezilla, hereis how

1. Download SSH Key
   [image]
2. Open filezilla,

   2.1 Go to  **Edit** > **Settings** > **Connection** > **SFTP** , Then click on **Add key file...**
   [image]

   2.2 Then, Press **ctrl+s** to open sitemanager, under **General tab**

   ```
    Protocol : SFTP - SSH File Transfer Protocol 
    Host : your_lightsail_static_ip
    Logon Type : Interactive
    User : light_sail_provided_user_name
   ```

[image]
That's it done.

Comment: I want to use SFTP to allow someone else to send a large file. Is there a way to do this without giving them my private key?

Comment: Better give ftp or need to create one more user to have restricted permissions.I'm not sure sorry.